# SQL Server procedure: selecting results inside dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This is more of a question I cant seem to find the answer to.

If I am using a stored procedure with dynamic SQL, and I select results from a table within the dynamic SQL, when I run the procedure, I do not see the results from the select. But if I do the select outside the dynamic SQL, and then run the procedure, I see the table results.

Notes: the table created inside dynamic SQL is a local temp table. Of course when

Is there a reason for this?

IE

```
USE SERVER
GO
CREATE PROC AnalyticsDW.ComputeBestTreatment
(
@ClientCode varchar(7)='FR'
)
as


declare @sql varchar(1000)
set @sql='
Bunch of code insert into #tableX
select * from #tableX'
EXEC (@SQL)
RETURN
go

exec AnalyticsDW.ComputeBestTreatment
```

Results do not show up when running the procedure, even though there are no errors shown.

vs

```
 USE SERVER
    GO
    CREATE PROC AnalyticsDW.ComputeBestTreatment
    (
    @ClientCode varchar(7)='FR'
    )
    as  

declare @sql varchar(1000)
set @sql='Bunch of code insert into ##tableX'
EXEC(@SQL)
select * from ##tableX
RETURN
go

exec AnalyticsDW.ComputeBestTreatment
```

Comment: You drop AnalyticsDW.ComputeBestTreatment and than you call it. Why

Comment: sorry, realized I hadnt copied the beginning fully. edited to just create the proc.

Comment: i have changed my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE PROC dbo.spComputeBestTreatment
 (
  @ClientCode varchar(7)='FR'
 )
  as  
begin



  declare 
  @createTable as nvarchar(4000),
  @tb as varchar(261);

   set @tb = '##tt';
   set @createTable = ' create table '+ @tb + ' (id int,Name varchar(20) ) '

    EXEC(@createTable);

   declare @Insert varchar(1000)
   set @Insert='insert into '+ @tb + ' values (1,''FirstName'') ';

   EXEC(@Insert)
   ;
    declare @Select varchar(1000)
   set @Select='SELECT * FROM '+ @tb 
     EXEC(@Select);

  end
   go

 exec dbo.spComputeBestTreatment
```

Comment: It does work when I use global temp tables as in this example...(when I call it outside the dynamic sql.)  problem is I want to see the results of a local temp table created inside dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified your code to insert actual data.  This does return results:

```
CREATE PROC ComputeBestTreatment
(
@ClientCode varchar(7)='FR'
)
as


declare @sql varchar(1000)
set @sql='
create table #tableX(i int)
insert into #tableX (i) values(1)
insert into #tableX (i) values(2)
select * from #tableX'
EXEC (@SQL)
RETURN
go
EXEC ComputeBestTreatment
```

Are you certain that the dynamic SQL in the real SP is actually inserting data into #tableX?

Comment: Yea, if I adjust the last select * into #table to select * into ##table I see the results when I run the proc. so I ill have to play around with it some more. Thanks for the help

Comment: I meant that the code I posted does return a result set and uses the local temp table #tableX.

Comment: Yea I saw the example does, which confuses me more about mine.

Comment: Are you able to flesh out a complete example that doesn't work?  That's what I was trying to do, but couldn't reproduce the problem.